# I forgot my password

Tags: security

I'm very worried because I forgot my password to log into my Elementary System and now I can't log in,  please help me as soon as possible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 20):

**Using recovery mode**:([using live usb/cd](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2818/2708))

I assume you are the only user and the administrator of your system.

To change password, hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while booting live usb/cd.  If that doesn't work, hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and hit <kbd>esc</kbd> key once after BIOS.

**Note**: Use arrow keys to navigate.

Select **advanced options** --> select **recovery mode**

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Now using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** and then hit  <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image: Imgur]

You should now see a prompt, something like this:

```
root@ravan:~#
```

It is read-only system, so you have to remount it with write permissions:

Run the command:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

then

```
passwd [user_name]
```

Enter new password.

[image: Imgur]

when you see `passwd: password updated successfully` then run `exit` and select **resume** option and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: well said!! cheers.

Comment: you can upvote my answer @dhanush_c =)

Comment: okay upvoted your answer.

Comment: Windows 7 let's you also do something like this but Windows 8 / 10 doesn't. Elementary OS should secure recovery mode like 8 / 10

Comment: I suspect this doesn't work if the assumptions that "you are the only user and the administrator of your system" don't hold true. I'm just getting started on elementary os, so they were true for me and it worked beautifully.

Comment: I've done as instructed. It showed password updated successfully. Still unable to login. I'm trying to reset elementary os

Answer (score 3):

**Using live USB/CD :** ([using recovery mode](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2814/2708))

1. Boot from live usb/cd and open terminal.
2. Use `gparted` or `fdisk -l` to identify elementary OS partition from the list.

   The partition is just something like `/dev/sda1`
3. Mount this somewhere (Be sure to select correct partition)

   ```
    sudo mount /dev/sda10 /mnt
   ```

**Note** :

- . In my system elementary OS partiton is `/dev/sda10`, replace it with yours.
- . If you have a `lvm` partiton, you need to mount it to `/mnt/`

---

4. Now run the following command as it is:

   ```
    for d in dev sys run proc; do sudo mount --bind /$d /mnt/$d; done
   ```
5. Now become root of system,

   ```
    sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
6. Set the password for the account:

   ```
    passwd [user_name]
   ```
7. Now reboot

   [image: Imgur]

<sub>source [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/435347/439451)</sub>