# When I click Administration account, it will not let me on the account. How can I unlock the settings from the guest account?

Tags: security, user

Whenever I click the admin account, it will not let me on it and only comes up with my background picture. This has happened for a while as I once turned off my laptop whilst it was going through an upgrade without me knowing. If anyone could help, that would be amazing!

Comment: did you lost your password? can you provide more details, clearly

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on this site pulled this answer up. The answer is for eOS Freya, but it shouldn't matter. Here is the link. [Unlock Password through Live boot](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/i-forgot-my-password)