# my os password was kept on asking again and again

Tags: greeter

I am unable to log in to my system after entering password.It is asking me the password again and again.My desktop is not loading.

Comment: sorry to ask this ... but ... is you caps lock on???

Comment: Does it go to a black screen for a second ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I forgot my password](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/i-forgot-my-password)

Comment: This sounds more like the gala or desktop process is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

If your screen isnt changing at all then the password your using is incorrect for whatever reason, you can reset it using this guide on another thread.

[I forgot my password](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/i-forgot-my-password)

Or alternitively at the log in screen you can press Ctrl+alt+f2 to go to a text terminal and try and log in, if it let's you in that way then x-windows could be broken and you should try:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg